# Change notifications through email

Tags: support, notifications

I'd like to change which topics on math are e-mailed to me.  When I first started on this site, I specified "Calculus" because I was in Calculus at the time.  I'd like to change it to Discrete Math now but I haven't been able to figure out how.  While typing this question, I found this [answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3494/56704), but I cannot find the "email settings" link the author spoke of.  How does one modify which math topics have new questions e-mailed to them?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get to it from the "preferences" tab in [your user profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/56704/andrew-falanga). From there I believe you click on either "Manage filtered questions emails" or "advanced tag subscriptions".